# Using UseState to Reset Value Before Adding Some

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I couldn't make the `setMajor` and `setMinor` work inside the function.

What happen is, it just overwrite some of the data inside `major` and keeps on adding data inside `minor`

I use this code to clear all the value inside the `major` but it's kinda messy and it looks like I'm not using the `useState` function properly.

```
major.forEach((tk) => {
      tk['material'] = ''
      tk['required'] = 0
      tk['actual'] = 0
      tk['difference'] = 0
      tk['crit'] = 0
      tk['percent'] = 0
    })
```

The `handleSelectInput` is a `select tag` that whenever I change the value it would send a request to the server to fetch the correct value for the `major` and `minor` variables

```
const majorStates = [
      {
        tank: 1,
        material: '',
        required: 0,
        actual: 0,
        difference: 0,
        crit: 0,
        percent: 0,
      },
      {
        tank: 2,
        material: '',
        required: 0,
        actual: 0,
        difference: 0,
        crit: 0,
        percent: 0,
      },...10],
[major, setMajor] = useState(tankStates),
[minor, setMinor] = useState([]),

const handleSelectInput= async (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target

    setMajor(majorStates) // not working
    setMinor([]) // not working

    await axios
      .put(`${PATH}/main-start`, { product: value })
      .then((res) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
          //See if data has a type major or minor
          //ParseFloat for decimal that's been returned as str
          if (res.data[i].type === 'MAJOR') {
            major[i].material = res.data[i].material
            major[i].required = parseFloat(res.data[i].required_wt)
            setMajor([...major])
          } else {
            res.data[i].required_wt = parseFloat(res.data[i].required_wt)
            setMinor([...minor, res.data[i]])
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
```

I have a `majorStates` because it is required that the 10 value is shown even if the fetch data is less than 10.

Sorry if it's a noob question

Comment: When you say "setMajor(majorStates) // not working" and "setMinor([]) // not working" can you be more specific? What *specifically* isn't working? I doubt that React is broken and not updating state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Based upon enqueueing a bunch of state updates in a loop I'm going to guess that what isn't working is that only the last enqueued state update is what you are seeing. This is caused by starting from the same stale state each loop iteration.

You are also mutating state, `major[i].material = res.data[i].material` is mutating the `major` element at index `i` for example.

## Solution

Use functional state updates to update from the previous state, ***not*** the state from the previous render cycle. Shallow copy the array ***and then*** also shallow copy any nested state/elements that are being updated.

```
const handleSelectInput= async (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target

  setMajor(majorStates) // reset
  setMinor([]) // reset

  await axios
    .put(`${PATH}/main-start`, { product: value })
    .then((res) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
        //See if data has a type major or minor
        //ParseFloat for decimal that's been returned as str
        if (res.data[i].type === 'MAJOR') {
          setMajor(major => major.map((el, index) => index === i ? {
            ...el,
            material: res.data[i].material,
            required: parseFloat(res.data[i].required_wt)
          } : el);
        } else {
          res.data[i].required_wt = parseFloat(res.data[i].required_wt)
          setMinor(minor => [...minor, res.data[i]])
        }
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, I was also wondering how to use a `functional update` cause it's been popping up in the console as a warning on some of my pages. Thank you :>